# I cannot deploy Alexa skill(built using jovo) on Heroku

Tags: node.js, windows, heroku, alexa-skills-kit, jovo-framework

So I am following this tutorial to deploy my Alexa skill on Heroku.
[How to Deploy your Alexa Skill and Google Action to Heroku](https://www.jovo.tech/blog/deploy-to-heroku/#introduction)

I reached the stage where I have to type this script in my windows cmd:

```
# Add Heroku App Remote
$ heroku git:remote -a
```

But, I keep getting this error:
[image]

Any idea what might be causing this issue?
Thanks guys :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in their tutorial. They created an app called `jovo-sample-app` on Heroku so the command would be:

```
heroku git:remote -a jovo-sample-app
```

Obviously if you're following the tutorial yourself the app name will be different.

Comment: Thanks! Updating the tutorial now

Answer (score 1):

Try `heroku git: remote -a [heroku-app-name]` from [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)